# Choose the best option according to certain characteristics

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I need to select the PERSON in each COMPANY that has the highest K, so it gets to look like this:

[image]

I managed to select the highest K within a range, using `=FILTER(B2:J4;G2:G4=max(G2:G4;1))` however I didn't figure out how to do that in a range that has a single company. I guess it might have something to do with the UNIQUE function, but I wasn't able to make it happen.

Could someone help?
I'm using this sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j1_-qYkg5Mp8bn4RCZ7w0yuI5TuTNJMN1EAaDh0RLE4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the max value of each person with this formula:

```
=QUERY(data!A:S; "SELECT D, MAX(G) GROUP BY D"; 1)
```

Do you need all the additional information as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do need to get all the extra info

Comment: I tested it and I believe it should be "Group By B" shouldn't it? I want the people with max K within a Company. However I tested changing it and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I managed to group by column B. My problem now is to show all the info and not only one piece of it

Comment: Well, it didn't completely solve it but it was a great hand. I managed to solve it using VLOOKUPs afterwards.